# How to get the PID of awesome-wm

Tags: linux, pid, awesome-wm

I'm trying to get the Process ID of my Awesome Windows Manager and failing miserably at it. Of the examples below I also tried using "awesome-wm" as my search string. I'm pretty sure there is an obvious solution to this.

So far I've tried:

```
$ pgrep awesome
$ pidof awesome
```

I also tried:

```
$ ps ax | grep awesome
$ xprop _NET_WM_PID
```

With no luck, no output, no PID (xprop desktop click outputs "_NET_WM_PID:  not found."). I'm certain its running, because its where I'm performing these tests in. Any ideas?

PS: Im running AWM under Crunchbang, a fork off Debian, if I run:

```
$ awesome -v && uname -a
```

I get:

```
awesome debian/3.4.13-1 (Octopus)
• Build: Jul 16 2012 13:57:50 for x86_64 by gcc version 4.7.1 (@keller)
• D-Bus support: ✔
Linux tzl 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.46-1+deb7u1 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Are you sure the process is there?  If you use `top` or maybe just `ps aux | grep $whoami` to get less stuff (assuming you're the one who initiated the process).

Comment: The problem was I was looking for the wrong process name. The PID I was looking for was 'x-session-manager' while I thought it would be called 'awesome' or 'awesome-wm'. Its funny that the xprop trick didn't work though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out the answer was that SLiM, which #! uses to control its Window Managers is using x-session-manager.

The name of the process I was looking for was not 'awesome', it was 'x-session-manager'.

So a quick:

```
$ wmctrl -m
```

Returned:

```
Name: awesome
Class: N/A
PID: 3091
Window manager's "showing the desktop" mode: N/A
```

Solving my PID troubles.

Comment: this is the right answer as it returns the PID of the running window manager. Especially useful for testing configurations through Xephyr.

Answer (score 1):

How about trying:

```
ps -e | grep awesome
```

This should list all of the processes in your computer and then you can search for awesome using grep.

Comment: Just tried that; "ps -e | grep awesome" returns nothing as well. Maybe I'm just looking for the wrong process name?